# Get index of object in array of objects on a particular id - javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ervin Howell",
"username": "Antonette",
"email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
"phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
"website": "anastasia.net"
},...];
```

I am passed id as 2. I want the index of array of objects where id=2. 
How can this be done in javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the obj with `Array#forEach` function, if actual index is the same as the given `id` in the arguments, assign it into the `objId` variable.

If there's no any objects with given `id` - function will log `-1`.

```js
let obj = [{id:1,name:"Leanne Graham",username:"Bret",email:"Sincere@april.biz",phone:"1-770-736-8031 x56442",website:"hildegard.org"},{id:2,name:"Ervin Howell",username:"Antonette",email:"Shanna@melissa.tv",phone:"010-692-6593 x09125",website:"anastasia.net"}];

function checkId(obj, id) {
  let objId = -1;
  obj.forEach((v,i) => v.id == id ? objId = i : v);
  console.log(objId);
}

checkId(obj, 2);
checkId(obj, 4);
```

Another approach, using `Array#find` and `Array#indexOf`.

```js
let obj = [{id:1,name:"Leanne Graham",username:"Bret",email:"Sincere@april.biz",phone:"1-770-736-8031 x56442",website:"hildegard.org"},{id:2,name:"Ervin Howell",username:"Antonette",email:"Shanna@melissa.tv",phone:"010-692-6593 x09125",website:"anastasia.net"}];

function checkId(obj, id) {
  let objId = obj.indexOf(obj.find((v,i) => v.id == id)) || -1;
  console.log(objId);
}

checkId(obj, 2);
checkId(obj, 4);
```

Comment: Can the same function be modified to search for strings as well?

Comment: @Arihant Like for a `name` key instead of `id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using each function:

```
var json = [
    {"id":"1","tagName":"apple"},
    {"id":"2","tagName":"orange"},
    {"id":"3","tagName":"banana"},
    {"id":"4","tagName":"watermelon"},
    {"id":"5","tagName":"pineapple"}
];

$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

  if(obj.id == 2){
    alert(idx);//will alert index where id = 2
  }

});
```

For more details please visit: https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-loop-over-json-string-each-example/

Answer (score 0):

This function will return an array of indexes if there is one or more matches:

```
function getIDs(obj,id) {
  var ret = [];
  obj.forEach((val,i) => val.id == id ? ret.push(i) : val); 
  return(ret);
}
var ids = getIDs(object,2);
console.log(ids);
```